# Can I append to a preprocessor macro?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor, x-macros

Is there any way in standard C—or with GNU extensions—to append stuff to a macro definition?  *E.g.*, given a macro defined as
`#define List   foo  bar`
can I append `bas` so that it `List` expands as if I’d defined it
`#define List   foo bar bas`?

I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
#define List    foo bar bas

#define List_   Expand(List)
#undef List
#define List    Expand(List_) quux
```

but I can’t figure out how to define the `Expand()` macro so it’ll do what I want.

**Motivation:**
I’m playing with discriminated/tagged unions along these lines:

```
struct quux_foo { int x; };
struct quux_bar { char *s; };
struct quux_bas { void *p; };

enum quux_type {quux_foo, quux_bar, quux_bas};

struct quux {
    enum quux_type type;
    union {
        struct quux_foo foo;
        struct quux_bar bar;
        struct quux_bas bas;
    } t;
};
```

I figure this is a good place for the X-macro.  If I define a macro
`#define quux_table X(foo) X(bar) X(bas)`
the enumeration & structure can be defined thus, and never get out of sync:

```
#define X(t) quux_ ## t,
enum quux_type {quux_table};
#undef X

#define X(t) struct quux_ ## t t;
struct quux {
    enum quux_type type;
    union {quux_table} t;
};
#undef X
```

Of course, the `quux_*` structures can get out of sync, so I’d like to do something like this, only legally:

```
struct quux_foo { int x; };
#define quux_table quux_table X(foo)

struct quux_bar { char *s; };
#define quux_table quux_table X(bar)

struct quux_bas { void *p; };
#define quux_table quux_table X(bas)
```

(Well, what I *really* want to be able to do is something like
`member_struct(quux, foo) { int x; };`
but I’m well aware that macros cannot be (re)defined from within macros.)

Anyhow, that’s my motivating example.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Boost.Preprocessor examples are fine, if you can show me how to make the X-macro technique work with that library.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely doable, if you don't insist on redefinition. Somewhat painful though if you use the raw preprocessor. Somewhat less painful with Boost.Preprocessor. Alas, my cold prevent me thinking straight enough to produce a method. Hopefully someone else will.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Effectively, no.

Macros are lazily evaluated.  When you `#define List_ Expand(List)`, its replacement list is the sequence of four tokens `Expand`, `(`, `List`, and `)`.  There isn't any way to expand a macro into a replacement list.

All macro replacement takes place when a macro is invoked.

I'd recommend looking at using the Boost.Preprocessor library for automatic code generation.  It's a bit of work, but you can accomplish some [fairly impressive things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818277/can-i-get-polymorphic-behavior-without-using-virtual-functions/3825181#3825181) using it.  It should be fully compatible with C.

Answer (score 14):

There is a way!

Using the new _Pragma keyword this can be achieved in gcc (though not with msvc)

If you pop a macro within it's own definition it will delay it's expansion until the macro is expanded for the first time. This allows you to make it's previous expansion part of it's own definition. However, since it is popped during it's expansion, it can only be used once

Here is some sample code to see it in action

```
#define pushfoo _Pragma("push_macro(\"foo\")") //for convenience
#define popfoo _Pragma("pop_macro(\"foo\")")

#define foo 1

pushfoo                           //push the old value
#undef foo                        //so you don't get a warning on the next line
#define foo popfoo foo , 2        //append to the previous value of foo

pushfoo
#undef foo
#define foo popfoo foo , 3

pushfoo
#undef foo
#define foo popfoo foo , 4


foo //this whole list will expand to something like popfoo foo popfoo foo popfoo foo , 4
    //which will in turn expand to 1 , 2 , 3 , 4

foo //the second time this will expand to just 1
```

This option should make automatic code generation a fair bit easier, though unfortunately only on gcc (maybe clang, haven't tested)

To be honest there is no reason I can find why this must work, it is most probably undefined behavior that happens to work. I'm guessing the reason is that after popping foo, the current macro being expanded is no longer associated with the name foo which allows the symbol `foo` to be expanded, but that is only my conjecture

Edit:

After testing on clang, this <del>does not</del> does work on clang.

I don't know why I thought clang did not work, maybe it didn't on a different machine. I definitely did get it to work with the code given though

Comment: You save my life.

Comment: Thank a lot. I was looking for such a solution

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this helps, but you can do vari arg macros. Mr. Conrad of the x264 project loves preprocessor abuse. If they sound like they might help you can find out more [Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html)

Comment: C99 variadic macros are nice (and I’ve used them), but this is not really relevant to my question.

(Not directly, at least, though I can imagine that the actual solution might _use_ variadic macros somewhere.)