# Is it possible to define _Generic's association-list dynamically?

Tags: c, gcc, generic-programming, c11

I have a template like this:

```
template.h
----------
// Declare a function "func_type()"
void JOIN(func_, T)(T t) { return; }
#undef T
```

which I use like this in order to generate the same function for different types:

```
example.c
---------
#define T int
#include "template.h"

#define T float
#include "template.h"
```

I would like to have a single `func` that I can use instead of `funct_int`, `func_float`, etc. My problem with `_Generic` is that it doesn't seem possible to define the association-list dynamically. In practical terms I'd like to have something like this:

```
#define func(TYPE) _Generic((TYPE), AUTO_GENERATED_LIST)
```

instead of manually defining every new type like this:

```
#define func(TYPE) _Generic((TYPE), int: func_int..., float: func_float...)
```

Here's an example of code that is not working: https://ideone.com/HN7sst

Comment: The generic selection is happening in compile time. You want your `AUTO_GENERATED_LIST` to be generated in compile time too?

Comment: > You want your AUTO_GENERATED_LIST to be generated in compile time too?   Yes

Comment: Well, you can't have function overloading in C. `void func(int x)` can't co-exist with `void func(float x)` in the same translation unit. Is the problem that you don't want to type out individually named functions that do the same thing, or what?

Comment: Not sure what is not working, but a macro is successfully expanding into the list: https://ideone.com/Jh7b8o

Comment: @Lundin `_Generic` exists for this reason, for overloading a function.

Comment: @EugeneSh. In your example you are defining the list manually. Instead I would like something like this https://ideone.com/HN7sst such that I can create the list dynamically every time a new `func_type` is defined from the template file.

Comment: You better write the code you would *like* to work which is not working, so we understand your usecase. Ah, actually you did. Place it into the question body

Comment: So you want each include file to take some macro, and redefine it to contain the previous content + extra. Am I correct? Let's decouple it from `_Generic`.

Comment: If that's the question, then it is pretty much a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550075/can-i-append-to-a-preprocessor-macro). It has a gcc-specific solution.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `push_macro` and `pop_macro` do not seem to work if I push/pop something like this `T: JOIN(func_, T)` because only the final T is expanded which means I end up with this: `_Generic((TYPE), float: func_float..., float: func_float...)`.

Comment: @grep9090 Check out the answer I posted, is this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Ah.. that `_Pragma` solution will work for the first call of `func` only...

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do can be achieved with the dreaded "X macros". Create a list such as

```
#define SUPPORTED_TYPES(X) \
  X(int,   "%d")           \
  X(float, "%f")           \
```

where `int` is the type and in this case I used printf format specifier as another item. These can be anything that counts as valid pre-processor tokens.

Then you can generate all functions through an evil macro like this:

```
#define DEFINE_F(type, fmt) \
void f_##type (type param)   \
{ printf(fmt "\n", param); }

SUPPORTED_TYPES(DEFINE_F)
```

This creates functions such as `void f_int (int param) { printf("%d\n", param); }`. That is, very similar to C++ templates - functions doing the same thing but with different types.

You can then write your _Generic macro like this:

```
void dummy (void* param){}
#define GENERIC_LIST(type, fmt) type: f_##type,
#define func(x) _Generic((x), SUPPORTED_TYPES(GENERIC_LIST) default: dummy)(x)
```

Here you define the generic asoc. list with `GENERIC_LIST`, using the `type` item but ignoring everything else. So it expands to for example `int: f_int,`.

A problem with this is the old "trailing comma" problem, we can't write _Generic like `_Generic((x), int: f_int,)(x)` the comma after `f_int` would mess up the syntax. I solved this with a `default` clause calling a dummy function, not ideal... might want to stick an `assert` inside that function.

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SUPPORTED_TYPES(X) \
  X(int,   "%d")           \
  X(float, "%f")           \


#define DEFINE_F(type, fmt)  \
void f_##type (type param)   \
{ printf(fmt "\n", param); }

SUPPORTED_TYPES(DEFINE_F)


void dummy (void* param){}
#define GENERIC_LIST(type, fmt) type: f_##type,
#define func(x) _Generic((x), SUPPORTED_TYPES(GENERIC_LIST) default: dummy)(x)

int main (void)
{
  int a = 1;
  float b = 2.0f;
  func(a);
  func(b);
}
```

Output:

```
1
2.000000
```

This is 100% ISO C, no extensions.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I've took some time to look into this. It's an interesting solution that I didn't think of, but unfortunately it does not seem to be the answer to my question. The reason is that it still requires to specify all the types in `SUPPORTED_TYPES` manually, whereas I'd like to **append** every new type automatically as they are created (a new type is "created" every time the template is included).

Comment: @grep9090 What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Template metaprogramming is a bad idea in C++... so imagine how bad an idea it is in C.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is this: **1)** define a generic function, say `binary_search_T()` **2)** the template can be included many times in order to end up with `binary_search_int()`, `binary_search_float()`, etc. **3)** have a single function `binary_search()` that automatically selects the correct `binary_search_T()` based on the input type. The last point, **3)**, is what I'm not able to do because I cannot create the association-list dynamically every time a new `binary_search_T()` is defined.

Comment: @grep9090 Then what's the reason why you can't use standard `bsearch`? It solves this in the "old school" way with function pointer callbacks. Because the search algo itself doesn't care about types.

Comment: I have many reasons, but the biggest one is that I want to apply this to other functions and `binary_search()` is just an example.

Comment: @grep9090 You can implement the same sort of API as `bsearch` though. Void pointers and callbacks is quite old-fashioned, but it's a well-known design pattern that might solve the problem.

Comment: I was using void and functions pointers before getting involved with _Generic, but in certain circumstances such as recursive functions they introduce a significant performance loss. For example C qsort() is notoriously slower than C++ sort() by a large margin. All my problems would be solved if the C preprocessor allowed to append to a macro, like this `#define FOO FOO, BAR` :-) I think I will use `func_int`, `func_float`, ...

Comment: @grep9090 I guess that's true, `qsort` will have a performance loss since function pointer callbacks can't be inlined, wheras a C++ compiler might "see" the whole implementation of a "functor" (overloaded operator) and inline the calls. I now recall a situation where I was bashing some other C veteran for using generic programming with void pointers instead of using type safe _Generic. They responded by asking me how to implement something like `bsearch` type safe, with _Generic and I couldn't come up with an answer then. Might be worth some further thought :)

Comment: @grep9090 Though in practice, if this is truly a performance bottleneck, you are likely better off manually writing the search/sort algo manually for the specific case, and then optimize it for the specific system, in terms of alignment and cache access etc etc. Library functions aren't always the best possible solution (but most of the time they are).